# Are elements ID inside an hidden div avaiable?

Tags: javascript, html

Supposing I have two `divs`: `data_new` and `data_old`, both are `style="display:none"`.

`data_old` is filled with an `AJAX` request. If the request returns something then:

- `data_old` -> `style="display:inline"`
- `data_new` -> `style="display:none"`
- `data_new` -> `.innerHTML = ''`

Otherwise if the request returns nothing:

- `data_new` -> `style="display:inline"`
- `data_old` -> `style="display:none"`
- `data_old` -> `.innerHTML = ''`

Both `divs` contain elements with the same `IDs`, and both `divs` contain a button which call the same `javascript function` which get the data from the elements on the `div`.

Are the elements of the first div `data_old` avaiable when `data_new` is visible?
Is there a risk that the called `JS function` get the data of those hidden and empty elements?

Comment: To the title: yes, but elements may not share IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its **against** the rules of HTML to have two elements with the **same id** on the **same page**. you can use a class. and even if a div is `display:none` it will still be present in the DOM tree.

Comment: I used the ID to get the value of those elements, but as you warn me have two elements with the same id is not good. I'll use another way to get the data, with only one div. Thank you